# Terminology: Vector, attributes, and matrices in a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, notation

I am confused about the terms "vectors", "attributes", and "matrix" when applied to a dataset.

I know that attributes are the features or columns of the dataset, and the matrix is $N \times M$ data with $N$ instances and $M$ attributes, but I am still confused about vectors? Is it the row of data, which means a dataset is a collection of vectors? And if we have N-D histogram, how can we represent the vectors?

Comment: If you have two questions, it's better to ask two questions separately. I edited out your second one, which you should ask as a separate question – you can see the text in the edit history [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/198394/revisions) for reference, though it's unclear to me exactly what you're asking in that one.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I wonder to know more about the rules and policies of posting and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

"Attributes" – also "features", "predictors", "independent variables", and some other terms – refer to the different dimensions of your dataset. For example, if you have a database of people with ages and incomes, age is one attribute/feature/whatever, income is another.

The most common way to represent this data for a machine learning algorithm is as a vector. So, a given person might correspond to a vector $\mathbf x = \begin{pmatrix}32 & 46000\end{pmatrix}$, where the first element is the person's age, and the second their income. If you have $M$ features, the vectors will be of length $M$.

When you have a full dataset of these things, one way to represent it is as a set of these vectors: a set of length $N$, where each element is a vector of length $M$. Sometimes it's more convenient to think about this instead as a matrix stacking up all the vectors, e.g. a matrix of size $N \times M$, where each row is one of the feature vectors from your dataset. So this might look like, for example, $$\mathbf X = \begin{bmatrix}32 & 46000 \\ 51 & 74000 \\ 19 & 12000 \\ 53 & 21000 \end{bmatrix}.$$
(You might also see it in the other order, with each feature across the rows and each instance as a column; this is just a convention difference that doesn't really mean anything.)

If we work with matrices, then we can talk about our models using linear algebra, which is sometimes easier and more efficient to implement than always doing everything as a sum over elements of a set.